# Tor first update: 404 not found

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, debian

I just downloaded Tor Browser via `apt-get install tor-browser` and when I run it, it starts a little update window saying the tarball will be downloaded, but then it says: *"Download Error: 404 not found."*
I'm running a fresh stable Debian 8.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're downloading from the repository and not just downloading the package from the [Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en)?